# The intersection of any family of principal ideals in a UFD is principal

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, gcd-and-lcm, unique-factorization-domains

I found this problem from Aluffi's Algebra Chapter 0 and only managed to find [one reference](https://commalg.subwiki.org/wiki/Principal_ideal) (without proof) to this statement online, so I'm posting this here for reference/verification.

#### Problem

Let $\mathcal{A} = \{(a_i)\}$ be a family of principal ideals in a UFD $R$.
Show that the ideal $I = \bigcap_i (a_i)$ is principal.

#### Solution (?)

$I$ is an ideal since it's an intersection of ideals.
Pick any $r_0 \in I$. If $(r_0) = I$ we are done, so suppose $(r_0) \subsetneq I$.
Then pick any $s \in I - (r_0)$.
Since $R$ is a UFD, greatest common divisors always exist so we can set $r_1 = \mathrm{gcd}(r_0, s)$.

By definition of gcd, the ideal $(r_1)$ is the smallest principal ideal containing the ideal $(r_0, s)$.
Since $(r_0, s) \subseteq (a_i)$ for each $i$,
we therefore have $(r_1) \subseteq (a_i)$ for each $i$.
Thus $(r_1) \subseteq I$ and we get
$$
(r_0) \subsetneq(r_0, s) \subseteq (r_1) \subseteq I.
$$
As long as $(r_n) \subsetneq I$ this process can be repeated fo find $r_{n+1}$ such that
$(r_n) \subsetneq (r_{n+1}) \subseteq I$, yielding an ascending sequence of principal ideals
$$
(r_0) \subsetneq \cdots \subsetneq (r_{n}) \subsetneq (r_{n+1}) \subseteq I.
$$
But since $R$ is a UFD this sequence must stabilize, which can only happen if we eventually have $(r_n) = I$.

#### Question

Does my solution look ok?

Isn't the generator of the ideal $I$ the least common multiple of the $a_i$'s? If this is true, does this statement imply that lcms exist for arbitrary families in UFDs? Can we say that gcds of arbitrary families exist in UFDs by the same logic?

Comment: I realise this has been solved but I'm just curious. Have you assumed that $R$ is a Noetherian Ring in the last step?

Comment: @August: no i have not, however UFDs satisfy the ACC for principal ideals (in fact this property characterizes UFDs among domains where irreducible elements are prime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution looks fine. And you are correct that any generator of the intersection will be an lcm. You can indeed also find arbitrary gcds in a UFD $R$. Take some subset $S\subseteq R$. Let $D$ be the set of principal ideals containing $S$. Of course, the unit ideal $(1)\in D$ so it's nonempty. As you've shown in your proof, the intersection $\bigcap_{(d) \in D} (d)$ has a principal generator, say $e$. Then $S\subseteq (e)$ so for all $s \in S$, $e \mid S$, i.e. $e$ is a common divisor of the elements of $S$. It is the greatest common divisor because if $d$ is another common divisor of the elements of $S$ then $S \subseteq (d)$, i.e. $(d) \in D$. Hence, $(e)\subseteq (d)$ and $d\mid e$.

Comment: Nice, thanks! Realizing now that this was actually part a) of the exercise, but it was just asking to show that in any domain satisfying this property, the gcd of two elements exist, but as you say it is not very hard to modify the argument to work for an arbitrary number of elements.

Comment: Glad I could help!